# Regex.Split exhibiting strange behavior

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex expression that I'm doing a split against another string and I'm getting weird results.

```
        string subjectString = "Triage|Follow Up|QA";
        string[] splitArray = null;
        try
        {
            splitArray = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<=(^|[^\\]))\|");

            foreach (var item in splitArray)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

The items being printed are:

Triage
e
Follow Up
p
QA

The regex behaves correctly in RegexBuddy, but not in C#. Any ideas on what's causing the weird behavior? Extra points for explaining why the split function is acting the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grouping `(…)` in your look-behind assertion is causing this. Try a non-capturing group instead:

```
@"(?<=(?:^|[^\\]))\|"
```

Or no additional grouping at all:

```
@"(?<=^|[^\\])\|"
```

Answer (score 1):

RegexBuddy does not yet emulate .NET's behavior of including text matched by capturing groups in the array returned by `Split()`.  To get the same behavior in .NET as in RegexBuddy, either change all your capturing groups `(...)` into non-capturing groups `(?:...)` or use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` to turn all unnamed groups into non-capturing groups.

By including the capturing groups in the returned array, .NET's `Split()` function makes it possible to include both the delimiters matched by the regular expression and the text between the delimiters in the array.  Splitting using the regex `<[^>]+>` gets you the text between the HTML tags, without the HTML tags.  Splitting using the regex `(<[^>]+>)` gets you the text between the HTML tags including the HTML tags.  (These simple regexes assume the input consists of valid HTML without any HTML comments.)